# Does the Lorentz transformation as $c \rightarrow ∞$ reproduce the Galilean transformation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

This question makes no sense so I think it must be a misprint. It says:

> Frame $Σ$ moves at speed v with respect to frame $Σ'$ in the common $x, x'$
>    directions.
>   The two frames are aligned at time $t = t_0
>  = 0$.
>
> (a) Write down the Galilean transformation as a matrix transforming the
>   $Σ$-frame coordinates $(ct, x)$ to the $Σ'$
>   coordinates $(ct'
> , x'
> )$. You can ignore the
>   transverse directions and work with $2 × 2$ matrices.
>
> (b) Write down the Lorentz transformation matrix. Take the limit $c → ∞$,
>   and show that this fails to reproduce the Galiliean transformation matrix.

My answer:

a) Is found easy enough $x'=x-vt$ and $t'=t$ so the transformation matrix is

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0  \\
    -v & 1  \\
   \end{pmatrix}
$$

b) It says take the limit as $c\rightarrow∞ $ but if we do this then $x'=\frac{x-vt}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \rightarrow \frac{x-vt}{\sqrt{1-0}}=x-vt$ and $t'=\frac{t-\frac{vx}{c^2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \rightarrow \frac{t-0}{\sqrt{1-0}}=t$ which is the exact same as the Galilean transformation.

Comment: Maybe the problem writer doesn't think $vx/c^2$ Goes to zero? You could always pick an $x$ big enough where it doesn't.

Comment: @user1379857 if $c \rightarrow ∞ $ the only way to make sure that x is bigger would be to make x=∞ and $\frac {∞}{∞}$ is undefined . So I don't see how that would work ?

Comment: Is this a question from a particular book, or is it from an unofficial problem sheet? I'd agree that it seems to be a misprint, but the wording of the question makes it seem rather deliberate.

Comment: @J.Murray It's from a problem sheet. the third part of the question goes . (c)  The reason for the failure above is that in the c → ∞ limit, the
variables ct and ct'
lose meaning.
So, write down the Galilean transformation as a matrix transforming the Σ-
frame coordinates (t, x) to the Σ0
coordinates (t
'
, x'
). i.e., the first coordinate
does not have the c factor. Write down the Lorentz transformation the same...

Comment: ...way, as a matrix transforming (t, x) to (t
'
, x'
).
Now show that the Lorentz transformation matrix reduces to the Galiliean
transformation matrix in the limit c → ∞.

Comment: which makes me think even more strongly that it is a misprint as it contradicts itself here ?

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on questions of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the added details in the comments, this question makes sense.  It's not talking about whether the Lorentz transformation itself reduces to the Galilean transformation in the limit as $c\rightarrow \infty$ (it does).  Instead, it's talking about the actual matrix
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\pmatrix{1 & -\frac{v}{c} \\ -\frac{v}{c} &1}$$

which transforms $\pmatrix{ct \\ x}$ into $\pmatrix{ct' \\ x'}$.

Comment: ah yes thank you , that does make a lot more sense :) one thing though in your matrix I think you meant to put $\beta=\frac{v}{c}$ instead of v, no ?

Comment: Ah yes, whoops.  Too used to natural units ;)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a misprint, and the problem is valid.

Your mistake is that you're expressing the transformation matrices in terms of $t$ and $t'$, instead of in terms of $ct$ and $ct'$ as the problem tells you to. If you express the matrices in terms of $ct$ and $ct'$, the bottom left corner of the Galilean transformation matrix will be $-v/c$ instead of $-v$, and the bottom left corner of the Lorentz transformation matrix will be

$$\frac{-v/c}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\ \ .$$

The limit of that expression as $c\to\infty$ is $0$, not $-v/c$, so the limit of the Lorentz matrix as $c\to\infty$ is different from the Galilean matrix. (Note that the problem doesn't have you take the limit of the Galilean matrix as $c\to\infty$.)

Comment: thank you I see now that I'd been making a silly mistake .